# Unable to get event receiver to work with Document Library

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, event-receivers

I have created a Document Library named `Attachments Library`. In the library I have created an additional *mandatory* column of `File Details`. I intened to use this field to capture some metadata about the file being uploaded.

When I click on the "new document" link in `Attachments Library` it shows me dialog to upload the file. Once the file is uploaded another dialog is shown with field `Name` `Title` and `File Details`. The fields `Name` and `File Details` are shown as mandatory (with asterisk symbol). What I want is that the field `File Details` should be auto-populated with some metadata of the uploaded file. For this purpose I have created an Event Receiver.

This is how my `Elements.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Attachments Library">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>EventReceiver1ItemAttachmentAdding</Name>
        <Type>ItemAttachmentAdding</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>AttachmentLibEventReceiver.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>EventReceiver1ItemAttachmentAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAttachmentAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>AttachmentLibEventReceiver.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

And this is how I written my event receiver:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace AttachmentLibEventReceiver.EventReceiver1
{
    public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        public override void ItemAttachmentAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAttachmentAdding(properties);
        }

        public override void ItemAttachmentAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPFile file = properties.ListItem.File;
            //properties.AfterProperties["File_x0020_Details"] = file.Name; // Did not work
            properties.ListItem["File_x0020_Details"] = file.Name; // Also did not work

            base.ItemAttachmentAdded(properties);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put the below code in `ItemAttachmentAdding` event also but no luck.

```
SPFile file = properties.ListItem.File;
//properties.AfterProperties["File_x0020_Details"] = file.Name; // Did not work
properties.ListItem["File_x0020_Details"] = file.Name; // Also did not work
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

From your description you need ItemAdding event receiver, not ItemAttachmentAdding event receiver.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry,I was thinking ItemAdded, not ItemAdding. In ItemAdded try this properties.ListItem["File Details"] = properties.ListItem.Name;